# Jquery Chosen Select scroll issue

Tags: jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I'm using JQuery chosen plugin, chosen single select. when i'm opening the dropdown which listing some set of values loaded in. also it's showing vertical scroll. i can able to scroll using scroll bar and mouse scroll, but i cant able to select the specific item. when mouse hovering the item, then the drop down taking me to the end of the list.

help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer for this.
thanks guys for spending time on this

the answer is

In **chosen.jquery.min.js** file the is code like

```
c = this.result_highlight.position().top + this.search_results.scrollTop(),
```

replace the above line by

```
c = this.result_highlight.position().top,
```

then the scroll issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2504#issuecomment-194773350
the problem seems to be solved when updating the jQuery library.

> I can confirm that upgrading to jQuery version 1.12.1 fixes the issue. 1.12.0 is the one with the issue.
>
> -- DrowningElysium